# What is the opposite of contains in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-query

Which query can I use in Elasticsearch to find/filter something that does **not** contain some value/text?

Is it possible in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse a query string [partial match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names) and you're done.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "field:value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean query which is recommended by elastic and it supports the `must_not` and definition of which from [this official doc is](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). **Please refer [warning of query string why it's not recommended](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).**

> The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents. Clauses
>   are executed in filter context meaning that scoring is ignored and
>   clauses are considered for caching. Because scoring is ignored, a
>   score of 0 for all documents is returned.

You can also include this in [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) which is cached by default and provide great performance benefit:

**More from the official doc which includes info about must_not param**

> Filter context is in effect whenever a query clause is passed to a
>   filter parameter, such as the filter or must_not parameters in the
>   bool query, the filter parameter in the constant_score query, or the
>   filter aggregation.

**Sample example**

**Index def**

```
{
    "mappings" :{
        "properties" : {
            "my_filter" : { --> not created for `must_not` filter
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
  "my_filter" : "foo"
}
{
  "my_filter" : "bar"
}
```

**Search query which filters out the `foo`**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {. --> this will execute in filter context, hence will be cached 
                "term": {
                    "my_filter": "foo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "partial",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {. --> not `foo` is removed.
                    "my_filter": "bar"
                }
            }
        ]
```